# When I search on multiple field included lookup with more then one field with $regex MongoDB perform slow

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I have Book collection which have Name, Description, Publisher ObjectID  field, Array of Authors ID,  Categories ID field etc. I need to search book with name, description, publisher name, author and category name with $regex.

To do that in aggregation pipe first I populate authors, publisher, categories with $lookup and then use $match with $or operator over the field.

My query works but it perform very slow ( approximately 11s ) where Book collection contain only 70 thousand documents.

What steps should I need in collection model, Indexing or Query good performance?

Book Model:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a2934934410bf8b0e547989"),
    "publisher" : ObjectId("5a27e7b68021772210b125d4"),
    "is_enabled" : true,
    "published_at" : ISODate("2017-12-07T12:31:15.166Z"),
    "author" : [ 
        ObjectId("5a27c5754b0efc477f37a131"),
        ObjectId("5a27c5754b0efc47737a1512"),
        ObjectId("5a27c5754b0efc477f37a145"),
    ],
    "category" : [ 
        ObjectId("5a27e22ffb6110b11c326cd7"), 
        ObjectId("5a27e22ffb6110b11c326ced"), 
        ObjectId("5a27e22ffb6110b11c326d2d"), 
        ObjectId("5a27e22ffb6110b11c326e45")
    ]
    "published_year" : "2017"
}
```

Query I executed:

```
Book.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $match: {
                "is_enabled": { $eq: true },
            }
        },
        {
            $lookup:
                {
                    from: "authors",
                    localField: "author",
                    foreignField: "_id",
                    as: "author"
                }
        },
        {
            $lookup:
                {
                    from: "categories",
                    localField: "category",
                    foreignField: "_id",
                    as: "category"
                }
        },
        {
            $lookup:
                {
                    from: "publishers",
                    localField: "publisher",
                    foreignField: "_id",
                    as: "publisher"
                }
        },
        {
            $match: {
                $or: [
                    { "author.name": new RegExp(params.expression, 'i') },
                    { "category.name": new RegExp(params.expression, 'i') },
                    { "publisher.name": new RegExp(params.expression, 'i') },
                    { "description": new RegExp(params.expression, 'i') },
                    { "name": new RegExp(params.expression, 'i') },
                    { "published_year": params.terms }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                previous_price: "$previous_price",
                price: "$price",
                name: "$name",
                seo_url: "$seo_url",
                click_url: "book",
                author: "$author",
                authorObj: {
                    name: { $arrayElemAt: ["$author.name", 0] },
                }
            }
        },
        { $sort: { name: 1 } }
    ]
)
    .skip(8 * (params.pagenum - 1))
    .limit(8)
    .exec((err, product) => {
        if (err)
            reject(err);
        else
            resolve(product);
    })
```

Comment: Yes, add "Indexing" to "name" field its increase performance.

Please see "$sort + $match Sequence Optimization" in link : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/

Answer (score 0):

You can create index for fields `is_enabled, author, category and publisher` like bellow.

```
db.coll.createIndex( { is_enabled: 1 } )
db.coll.createIndex( { author: 1 } )
db.coll.createIndex( { category: 1 } )
db.coll.createIndex( { publisher: 1 } )
```

that will increase the performance for first match stage and for lookup.

you can also create index for `name, description and published_year` but I am not sure how will affect of this index for last match stage because you used `$or` condition. As far I know still unable to optimize indexed queries that uses `$or, $in` (<=3.2). You can try that. It will be helpful if you use `$and` condition query. If you use `$and` query then you can also create ***multi key index*** for `name, description and published_year`. like

```
db.coll.createIndex( { name: 1, description: 1 published_year:1 } )
```

and then you should follow the same order in match condition

```
{$match: { name: 'xx', description:'yy', published_year: 2017}}
```